# Validate empty text fields whenever I click on button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have coded for add and remove input text fields dynamically in AngularJS. Here is my code:

**My HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="hobbies">Hobbies</label>
    <span ng-repeat="hobby in hobbies track by $index">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type='text' ng-model='hobbies[$index]' class="form-control pull-right"/>
            <button ng-click = "addHobby()" ng-show="$last">+</button>
            <button ng-click = "removeHobby($index)" ng-show="hobbies.length > 1">-</button>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.hobbies = [''];

$scope.addHobby = function() {
    $scope.hobbies.push('');
}

$scope.removeHobby = function(index) {
    if(index >= 0){
        $scope.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

In this how can I validate empty text fields whenever I click on `+` button?

Comment: In the addHobby function, you could add a check for empty fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `addhobby` function to something can validate empty text fields, like:

```
$scope.addHobby = function($index) {
    if($scope.hobbies[$index])
        $scope.hobbies.push('');
}
```

and your html button to:

```
<button ng-click = "addHobby($index)" ng-show="$last">+</button>
```

This way your addHobby function will add an hobby whenever your current input text field it's not empty.

Comment: Actually he down't even need the index since it's always the last